# Update collection from angular js api using mongoose

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

In my collection schema, I have code as below

Product.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');    
    var ProductSchema = new Schema({
         name : String,
         id : String,
         price : Number

    });
    mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

---

WishList.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var WishListSchema = new Schema({
    customer : String,
    products: {
        type: [{
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product'
        }]
    },
    billAmount : Number
});
WishListSchema.methods = {
addProduct: function(_product) {

        var deferred = q.defer();
        var Product= mongoose.model('Product');
        var self = this;
        var product = new Product(_product);

        product.save(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            if (err) {
                return deferred.reject(err);
            } else {
                self.update({
                    $push: {
                        products : product
                    }
                }, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return deferred.reject(err);
                    } else {
                        return deferred.resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
        });       
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
mongoose.model('WishList', WishListSchema);
```

---

APIrouteDefintion.js

```
 app.post('/api/order/:orderId/addToCart',auth.requiresLogin,controller.addProduct);
```

---

When I call addProduct function this way, I get my product id updated under the wishList, but not the name and price. Please let me know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is the normal behavior for Mongoose, the id added to wishlist is a reference to the product document.

If you want to return the name and price of the product you have to add a static to your wish list e.g.:

WishListSchema.statics.load = function(id, cb) {
    this.findOne({
        _id: id
    }).populate('product', 'name price').exec(cb);
};

But don't quote me not near the reference material.  But your current result is normal i.e. :only id returns", what you want i.e. "name and price is an added feature".

Just to assure yourself look at the document in the Mongo database you will see that only the id is stored.

e.g.   "product":{
    "$oid":"53110db1edf8384039ed0bb5"
  }